# Marshal.GetExceptionPointers и WPF-овский DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf, pinvoke

Доброго времени суток. Есть `WPF-приложение` + дампер(`MiniDumpWriteDump`). Нужно при возникновении `UnhandledException` в приложении создавать `minidump` и затем ложить приложение.

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
      Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

[DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentThreadId", ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern Int32 GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();

private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  var pointers = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers(); //тут все ок :)
  var thread = GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
  handleAppException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception, thread, pointers);
}

private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  var pointers = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers(); //тут IntPtr.Zero :(
  var thread = GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
  handleAppException(e.Exception as Exception, thread, pointers);
}

private void handleAppException(int threadId, IntPtr pointers)
{
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    MiniDump.CreateMiniDump("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\dump.dmp", threadId, pointers);
  }).Wait();
}
```

Если в программе возникает ошибка связанная с другим потоком, например:

```
  Thread t = new Thread(() =>
  {
    throw new Exception("Thread exception!");
  });
  t.Start();
```

то выполняется `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` и `Marshal.GetExceptionPointers();` корректно возвращает указатель.
А если ошибка возникает в UI thread-е, например:

```
throw new Exception("UI thread");
```

то выполняется `Current_DispatcherUnhandledException` и `GetExceptionPointers` возвращает `IntPtr.Zero`.

**Вопрос:**
Как мне получить `ExceptionPointers` при ошибке в `UI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел **решение**:

использовать `Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter` вместо `Current.DispatcherUnhandledException`.